Need translation of this painting inscription. Looks like Chinese Seal Font/script (Characters identified: 柔豐)
I have an image of a pictures inscription that appears to be in Chinese Seal Script/Font.
Here is the image in black and white. Thank you!

It's 柔丰 (柔豐 traditional Chinese) in small seal script
You can type in 柔丰 on this website to verify: https://anfei.github.io/xiaozhuan/

Thank you but what does it say or mean? In English.

When I put image into Google Translate it says "Can't detect text. Language may not be supported".

We write 豐 in Chinese, not 豊. 豊 is Japanese.

Per 汉典, "豊"同"豐(plenty)", however, it has another pronunciation [lǐ], which means "古代祭祀用的礼器(Ancient ritual vessels)".  But here the character is "豐". https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%B1%8A

@JimmySchoster 柔=soft, 丰=rich, plentiful. But 柔丰 is not a word. I guess it's someone's name, doesn't necessarily mean anything.

@dROOOze Updated. Thanks for the correction.

Thank you! Makes good sense to be the name of the artist perhaps. Thank you again.


Here is a color picture of same.
